Probability that $all$ English letters appear in text corpus string size $n, n≥26$
Letter frequency for English text corpus is known. In 1st approximation let's consider equiprobable the double, triple, etc. letter combinations (e.g. aa, ab, aaa, aba, etc.)
How to find the probability that $all$ English letters appear in text corpus string size $n, n≥26$?
English alphabet has 26 letters, so the probability is zero for n<26. Punctuation signs and spaces can be ignored or taken in account - up to you preference. For simplicity we can assign probability $p_a$ to a specific English letter, where $1 \leq a \leq 26$ is index number of the letter in the English alphabet. I'd highly appreciate any insight on how to take it further with letter-combination frequencies $p_{a_1,a_2}$, $p_{a_1,a_2,a_3}$, etc.

In general, this is a hard problem, the expression is basically an inclusion-exclusion argument, with $2^{26}$ terms.

Thanks, @ThomasAndrews. Is it hard even in the case of ignoring n-grams considering them equiprobable ?

If you just mean each letter is equally likely, just say that. I have no, idea what you mean by n grams, but I assume you mean that each letter is independent.

@ThomasAndrews I mean single letters are not equally likely, but their combinations are like ab, ac, ..., zy, zz .

If you ignore the multiple letter combination probabilities this is the coupon collector's problem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem.

Assuming each letter in the sequence is independent. Let $S={1,2,\dots,26}$ and for  $T\subseteq S,$  define $p_T=\sum_{i\in T} p_i.$ Then inclusion-exclusion gives the probability: $$\sum_{T\subseteq S} (-1)^{26-|T|}p_T^n.$$ if all the letters are equally likely, this simplifies to: $$\sum_{t=0}^{26} (-1)^{26-t}\binom {26}{t}\frac{t^n}{26^n}.$$

A string of size $n$ could be seen as a function ${1, 2, ..., n} \to {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t, u, v, w, x, y, z}$. All English letters would then appear in a string if and only if the corresponding function is surjective. So, the probability is just the number of surjections ${1, 2, ..., n} \to {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t, u, v, w, x, y, z}$ divided by $26^n$, right?

If that is what you want. By the way, eqiprobable is not the word you wanted. You want independence.

@GeoffreyTrang That's true if every letter in the string is uniformly and independently selected from the $26$ letters of the alphabet. The question supposes that the frequency of letters is non-uniform.

In real life, long-enough strings randomly chosen from the English text corpus will have a tendency to contain all the letters due to the fact that people deliberately invent such strings. The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog's back.

@ThomasAndrews if you could post your comment as an answer with a bit more explanation I would highly appreciate it.

Assuming the letters in each position are independent, Let $S=\{1,\dots,26\},$ and let $p_i$ to be the probability of letter $i$ for each $i\in S.$ Define for each $T\subseteq S,$ $p_T=\sum_{i\in T}p_i,$ then a standard inclusion-exclusion argument gives that the probability of getting all letters in a word of,length $n$ is:
$$\sum_{T\subseteq S}(-1)^{|T|}p_T^n$$
That's $2^{26}$ terms in the sum, which is huge. Not impossible to calculate, but it would take some time.
I believe the maximal probability is when each $p_i$ is equal. But I forget how to prove that. Seems like it might be AM/GM-related.

If the letters are independent, the probability in question is:
$$
P(n)=n!\sum_{n_i>0}^{\sum_in_i=n}\prod_i\frac{p_i^{n_i}}{n_i!},
$$
where $p_i$ is the probability of the $i$-th letter ($i=1\dots26$).

This can also be written in terms of multinomial: $$\sum_{n_1,\dots,n_{26}>0}\binom{n}{n_1,\dots,n_{26}} \prod p_i^{n_i}$$ This is all the terms of $(p_1+\cdots+p_{26})^n$ except for the ones with one or more exponent is zero.

It is also the coefficient of $z^n$ in the expansion expansion of $$\prod_1^26 \left(e^{p_iz}-1\right)$$

@ThomasAndrews Thanks for your comment. Your approach is of course superior for large $n$. But I think my expression can be useful for proving the maximal probability property you mentioned.

The number of partitions of $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ into $26$ nonempty subsets is the Stirling number of the second kind $S_2(n,26)$.  The probability (assuming the letters are equiprobable and independent) is then
$ 26!\; S_2(n,26)/26^n $.

A quick Google search found this on the asymptotics of $S_2(n, m)$:
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/270473525_Asymptotics_of_the_Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind_revisited/link/56896dba08ae1975839aaaf6/download?_tp=eyJjb250ZXh0Ijp7ImZpcnN0UGFnZSI6InB1YmxpY2F0aW9uIiwicGFnZSI6InB1YmxpY2F0aW9uIn19

Letters are not equiprobable.
